# List of all invalid operations that throw an ArithmeticException() in Java?

Tags: java, exception

Is there a comprehensive list of all possible operations (such as division by zero) that throw an `ArithmeticException` in Java?

Put in another way: For instance, one could catch these exceptions as

```
catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And for division by zero the message would read:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at [filename:line number]
```

Surely this message is a predefined quantity made available to the compiler.
So my question is, where can I find a complete list of arithmeticexception messages which a compiler can possibly generate?

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing `new ArithmeticException("A new message!")`. The message isn't predefined in the compiler. So, strictly speaking, there are an infinite number of `ArithmeticException` messages that a compiler can generate.

Comment: @marstran I am referring to the `printStackTrace();` messages, not custom made ones.

Comment: So from `at [filename:line number]`? There's still an infinite amount. What would it give from a possibly non-terminating recursive function for example (disregarding `StackOverflowException`)?

Comment: The message printed by `printStackTrace` is the one given as a string in the constructor of `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: It sounds like you might be planning on having code that takes action based on the text of an exception’s message.  That is a bad idea, as the message can change at any time, even in a minor release.  It also may be localized for the current runtime’s locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no complete list, but below are some causes.

There seem to be two types:

1. Division by zero.
2. Inexact result when exact result requested (e.g. overflow or rounding).

So far, this is what I've found:

- [Normal and Abrupt Completion of Evaluation (JLS §15.6)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6):

  > An integer division ([§15.17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)) or integer remainder ([§15.17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)) operator throws an `ArithmeticException` if the value of the right-hand operand expression is zero.
- [`Math.addExact(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-),
  `Math.subtractExact(int x, int y)`,
  `Math.multiplyExact(int x, int y)`,
  `Math.incrementExact(int a)`,
  `Math.decrementExact(int a)`,
  `Math.negateExact(int a)`:

  > Throws: `ArithmeticException` - if the result overflows an int
- `Math.addExact(long x, long y)`,
  `Math.subtractExact(long x, long y)`,
  `Math.multiplyExact(long x, long y)`,
  `Math.incrementExact(long a)`,
  `Math.decrementExact(long a)`,
  `Math.negateExact(long a)`:

  > Throws: `ArithmeticException` - if the result overflows an long
- `Math.toIntExact(long value)`:

  > Throws: `ArithmeticException` - if the argument overflows an int
- `Math.floorDiv(int x, int y)`,
  `Math.floorDiv(long x, long y)`,
  `Math.floorMod(int x, int y)`,
  `Math.floorMod(long x, long y)`:

  > Throws: `ArithmeticException` - if the divisor y is zero
- [`BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_UNNECESSARY):

  > If this rounding mode is specified on an operation that yields an inexact result, an `ArithmeticException` is thrown.
- `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, int roundingMode)`,
  `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`,
  `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode)`,
  `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, RoundingMode roundingMode)`,
  ...:

  > Throws: `ArithmeticException` - if divisor is zero

Comment: The first one is in the JVM code whereas the others are in the JDK code. If you include JDK exceptions then you would also need to include BigDecimal and BigInteger classes for example (it's probably possible to run a grep on the JDK source to find all the occurrences).

Answer (score 1):

Here a list created with Eclipse by searching for the constructor of ArithmeticException in the JRE8:

```
java.lang - rt.jar - C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\lib - Test
    Math
        addExact(int, int)
        addExact(long, long)
        decrementExact(int)
        decrementExact(long)
        incrementExact(int)
        incrementExact(long)
        multiplyExact(int, int)
        multiplyExact(long, long)
        negateExact(int)
        negateExact(long)
        subtractExact(int, int)
        subtractExact(long, long)
        toIntExact(long)
java.math - rt.jar - C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\lib - Test
    BigDecimal
        byteValueExact()
        checkScale(BigInteger, long)
        checkScale(long, long)
        checkScale(long)
        checkScaleNonZero(long)
        commonNeedIncrement(int, int, int, boolean)
        divide(BigDecimal, MathContext) (2 matches)
        divide(BigDecimal) (3 matches)
        divideToIntegralValue(BigDecimal, MathContext)
        intValueExact()
        longValueExact() (2 matches)
        pow(int, MathContext) (2 matches)
        pow(int)
        shortValueExact()
    BigInteger
        BigInteger(int, int, Random)
        byteValueExact()
        clearBit(int)
        flipBit(int)
        getPrimeSearchLen(int)
        intValueExact()
        longValueExact()
        mod(BigInteger)
        modInverse(BigInteger)
        modPow(BigInteger, BigInteger)
        nextProbablePrime()
        pow(int)
        probablePrime(int, Random)
        reportOverflow()
        setBit(int)
        shortValueExact()
        testBit(int)
    LongOverflow
        check(BigDecimal)
    MutableBigInteger
        divide(long, MutableBigInteger)
        divideKnuth(MutableBigInteger, MutableBigInteger, boolean)
        euclidModInverse(int) (2 matches)
        modInverse(MutableBigInteger)
        modInverseMP2(int)
        mutableModInverse(MutableBigInteger)
java.text - rt.jar - C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\lib - Test
    DigitList
        shouldRoundUp(int, boolean, boolean)
java.time - rt.jar - C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\lib - Test
    Duration
        create(BigDecimal)
        dividedBy(long)
```

this does not contain methods that call this methods...